# Every representation of a finite group is completely reducible

Tags: representation-theory

Is this equivalent to saying that a representation is diagonalizable matrix in matrix form?

Comment: This question needs more details.  Are these representations over $\mathbb{C}$?  It's true that every such representation of a finite group is completely reducible, and that every element maps to a diagonalizable matrix.  Are you asking if these properties coincide for representations of infinite groups?  Are you asking for a proof of reducibility from diagonalizability?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was not asking about infinite groups. The fact that every element maps to a diagonalizable matrix is because the finite group rep is equivalent to unitary rep, correct?

Comment: I don't know what "equivalent" means, but yes, this seems like a good way to look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that would be saying that every representation is completely reducible to a direct sum of 1-dimensional representations. For instance, $S_3$ the symmetric group on 3 letters has a simple (thus already reduced) representation on $\mathbb{C}^2$ where a 3-cycle $\tau$ acts as rotation through $2\pi/3$ and a 2-cycle $\sigma$ acts as a reflection. Now matrices representing each of these operators are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$, but they don't commute with each other, so they aren't *simultaneously* diagonalizable. That is, there's no basis for this representation in which $S_3$ acts by diagonal matrices. And that's good news, because otherwise it couldn't be simple.

Comment: So I guess the diagonal matrix representation of irreducible parts in completely reduced representation is actually a block form, right?

Comment: Bringing to block form means decomposing into subrepresentations.

Comment: @KyleLee yes, that's right.